# Azure is there any limit for PUT request?

Tags: blob, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure sdk for PHP. I have e.g 200 files to put in Azure storage. File size is between 100 KB to 1MB. My algorithm inserting is as follows.

1. Create Azure Blob Service.
2. Create new container (unique name).
3. Insert 10 files (createBlockBlob).
4. Create new container
5. Insert 10 Blobs.
   ... and so on.

Let sat after 30-40 insertion i getting error:

> Exception 'HTTP_Request2_MessageException' with message 'Malformed response: '

Any suggestions what can be a reason of this error?

Comment: Does this happen with HTTP or HTTPS? Or both?

Comment: @SerdarOzler-Microsoft i tested it only on https. I think that something wrong is with Socket5 class. I tested the same algorithm but using Guzzle class (cURL) and everything work fine.